# Need Help Using Delegate To Change UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I have setup a delegate method, so that when user selects cell from VC2, it updates the header text of VC1 then pops back to it.

Now I need to add some code that will let me change the array that loads the UITableView in VC1, what is the easiest way to do this?

In VC 1

```
- (void)didChooseValue:(NSString *)string 
{
    self.databaseName = string;
    NSLog(@"Database Name: %@", self.databaseName);
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

In VC 2 - `didSelectRowAtIndex`

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didChooseValue:)])
    {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(didChooseValue:) withObject:myString];
    }
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to modify an array?

Comment: No, i know how to do that, im asking how to setup a delegate method that will let me modify the array in VC 1 depending on which cell I selected from VC 2.

Comment: Modify the array in what way?  What is the user selecting in VC2, and how does it relate to the contents of the array rendered in VC1?

Comment: In V2, user can select a Category, like car manufactors, then it pops back to V1 and it should load a table (array) of car models for that manufactor.

Comment: I see.  And where are these car models coming from?  Hard-coded arrays in memory?  Local sqlite database?  Queried from a remote server via JSON or XML?  If it's being queried from a local or remote source, do you already have this code working?

Comment: Right now I just have it so it loads on the arrays by default in `viewDidLoad`, but what I want is to change `carArray` depending on which cell user chose from VC 2.  This is the code to get the array from SQLite Database: `NSMutableArray *carModels = [[Database sharedDatabase] getMazdaModels]; self.carAray = carModels;`

Comment: Can I assume that VC1 and VC2 are UIViewControllers and not some kind of voltage controlled devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the code in this delegate method itself. Try something like:

```
- (void)didChooseValue:(NSString *)string 
{
    self.databaseName = string;
    NSLog(@"Database Name: %@", self.databaseName);
    NSMutableArray *carModels = nil;

    if([string isEqualToString:@"Mazda"])
        carModels = [[Database sharedDatabase] getMazdaModels]; 
    else if([string isEqualToString:@"Nissan"])
        carModels = [[Database sharedDatabase] getNissanModels]; //And so on depending on the number of models
    else
        carModels = [[Database sharedDatabase] getDefaultModels];

    self.carAray = carModels;
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```